# Should I compile D program on Linux for windows?

Tags: d

Is there any way to compile a D program under linux for a windows operating system?

Comment: What compiler? DMD, GDC or LLVM? GDC and LLVM should have support for this.

Comment: Actually I am a beginner, currently I use dmd, but I can easy change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to run the windows version of dmd under [wine](http://www.winehq.org/). You could set up a cross compiler, but that'll be a lot of extra hassle for the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

*Answer to your first question ("Should I ...")*: It depends mainly on your development environment. If you work exclusively on Linux, then it is a good idea to setup cross-compiler and build Windows applications on Linux.

*Answer to the second question ("Is there...")*: Yes, there is - by using a [cross-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) capable of targeting Windows platform.

Both GDC and LDC can be built so they can target Windows 32bit or 64bit straight from your Linux box. You can find hundreds of resources on this topic on the Internet. Writing a guide how to build GDC cross-compiler is time-consuming, but if you somehow fail to do it on your own I will write a simple step-by-step guide how to do this.

Comment: there's already a wiki page for GDC: http://gdcproject.org/wiki/Cross%20Compiler I'd use crosstool, it makes the whole process quite easy: http://gdcproject.org/wiki/Cross%20Compiler/crosstool-NG  However, the gdc windows binaries use the tdm gcc patches and they use some gdc patches which are not in the standard gdc repository, so you the cross compiler wouldn't produce exactly the same code. You'd have to ask Daniel Green for the patches: https://github.com/venix1/GDC/tree